# How to add bean method call to camel route bolder

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am a newbie to apache camel. My requirement is to add a method call to route builder and to pass a pojo 
 instance to this method as an argument. Here is the use case.

```
Class Pojo {
Getters and setters
}

Class Component {
Void process(Pojo pojo) {
// Logic goes here.
}
```

I want to call this component class as part of the route builder and pass the pojo instance an argument. Can you please provide sample code  for the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can see some examples [here](http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess what you need is - http://camel.apache.org/class.html

Also, you can specify whatever argument you want in the method signature.. you need to take care that the message body in the route at that particular point is either the same POJO or something which can be converted to the POJO using registered transformers